# Jasmine & jasmine-reporters on nodejs missing output

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I have some Jasmine unittest and am testing them with nodejs.
Using nodejs 0.10.31, jasmine-npm 2.2.1 and jasmine-reporters 2.0.5

The tests run, but i don't get any output via the jasmine-reporters.
The logging shows the line '16 specs, 0 failures' but no xml file to be found.

After more than day of testing various setups and google-ing i'm almost ready to give up :(

The current setup is to use a helper.

```js
var reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

var junitReporter = new reporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    savePath: '..',
    consolidateAll: false
});

var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();

jasmineEnv.beforeAll(function () {
    console.log('Before all...');
    jasmineEnv.addReporter(junitReporter);
});
```

This code is being called, also i have tried to add the reporter instead of the `beforeAll`, that seems to do exactly the same.

I have added some logging to the various methods inside the JUnitXmlReporter, i seem most of them printed as expected, except for the `jasmineStarted`, `jasmineDone` and `writeFile`. Especialy the lack of `writeFile` seems to be a key in my problem.

What am i doing wrong of what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jesse: Thanks for your reply. Adding the reporter in the beforeAll was an experiment after various other failed locations, most of them had the same behavior.

After a deep dive in the scripts involved i found the following problem.

When 'simply' add the reporter in the helper-script you add your reporter to an already running runnen, one that has not ran any specs but the execute is started. And thus is there already a ConsoleReporter added; the onComplete of the ConsoleReporter calls `exit(0)` or `exit(1)` and this kills/exits the process in the mids of passing the complete state to all other reporters.
(also described https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/32)

I changed the `addReporter`-method so it unshifts the new reporter in the array instead of pushing. This way the newly added reporters get called before the `ConsoleReporter` and thus also before the `defaultOnComplete` exits the process.

In my [issue/question](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/32) they told me this exit-behavior of the ConsoleReporter is changed so all reporters can enjoy the complete-event.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by putting Jasmine specific configuring up-front in a spec runner. In my **spec/** directory, I defined a file named **spec_runner.js** with the following:

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine'),
    reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

var junitReporter = new reporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
  savePath: __dirname,
  consolidateAll: false
});

var jasmine = new Jasmine();

jasmine.loadConfigFile("spec/support/jasmine.json");
jasmine.addReporter(junitReporter);
jasmine.execute();
```

Also inside **spec/**, I have a **unit/** and **integration/** directory where I have my unit and integration tests respectively. It's also important to have a **spec/support/** directory containing your configuration options for Jasmine. This directory should be created if you issue **jasmine init** from the root of your project.

**spec/support/jasmine.json** should look like the following for this example:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

You should get JUnit XML output if you issue: **jasmine spec/test_runner.js** from the root of your project at a command line prompt.

Lastly, to change the path to which your JUnit XML is written, you must change the **savePath** value in the object literal that is passed when creating a new instance of JUnitXmlReporter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any examples of calling beforeAll from the jasmine env object on github or the jasmine docs.

Try pulling the addReporter command outside of the beforeAll function.

```
jasmineEnv.addReporter(junitReporter);
```

Also make sure the file with this code is executed by your test runner before any of your specs are run.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but where does `jasmineEnv` come from?

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jasmineEnv&type=Code

You can fetch it from a global that jasmine exposes. ie. `var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv()`..